# What issues could I run into if my bundle id doesn't exactly match my reverse url?

Tags: android, ios

I have a url that is hyphenated. For example, `www.my-url.com`.

When I create my mobile apps, the bundle id will then be `com.my-url.mobile` on iOS, but `com.my_url.mobile` on android. This is because iOS allows hyphens in bundle ids, and android does not.

Are there any issues I could run into because my android id doesn't *exactly* match my url?

Comment: I’ve seen old questions here that resulted in problems with iOS push notifications when bundle identifiers had hyphens in them (though I don’t know if those concerns are still applicable). You might not be doing push notifications now, but it’s something to consider if you might ever eventually do that. You might want to research that before locking into a bundle identifier with a hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ni generally you won't face any issue your bundel I'd is just unique I'd for your app.

In most case like [Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) you have to specify your bundel I'd they just won't automatically keep same as your site url i hope i explained enough for your doubt.

Also don't forget to check android [offical doc releted to bundel id](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id)